# Connect django model to different table name with same structure

Tags: python, django

I have a database where I import data from the stock market. This will all be identical tables with only the date differing. How would I connect a django model with a dynamic table name?

Comment: Is it in same database you are using in for django or different?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `db_table` option in models `Meta` for specifying different table name like this.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

This will work only if your table is in the same database you are using as default in django settings. However if this database if different than your default database, you have to add it in `DATABASES` configuration under another name and make your own database router for proper routing like this.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    ...
    'other': {
        'NAME': 'primary',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'spam',
    }, 

}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.YourRouter']
```

**routers.py** (create it)

```
class YourRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.model_name == 'yourmodel':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.model_name == 'yourmodel':
            return 'other'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return False

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        return False
```

Comment: Yes the db_table I understand. But this needs to be dynamic. db_table = table_name

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourRouter:
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.model_name == 'yourmodel':
        model._meta.db_table == 'your_new_table'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    if model._meta.model_name == 'yourmodel':
        model._meta.db_table == 'your_new_table'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    return False

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    return False
```

I think, it will work, but make some trouble with relations